# Unable to dynamically create more than one instance of Android Fragment

Tags: android, dynamic, android-fragments

I'm trying to use a Fragment for a piece to instantiate multiple times in my app, but I cannot create more than the first one; the FragmentTransaction code is called, but I never get the second instance to show on the screen.  (Or maybe the first is overwritten, even though I'm calling "add".)

I've heard about the `ListFragment` and I'm about to experiment with that if I can't get this working... but why can I not create multiple instances of this fragment?

Here is what I modified in MainActivity.java.  (BTW: calling `addSlotFragment` twice here isn't what I want in the end... I just plan to call it from a button-push... but I figure if I can get this simple example to work then I can probably get to my final solution.)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addSlotFragment();

    addSlotFragment();
  }


  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
  private void addSlotFragment() {
    System.out.println("adding fragment");
    // add time-slot fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    TimeSlotFragment fragment = new TimeSlotFragment();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.time_slot_container, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
  }
}
```

... and the piece I added to the default activity_main.xml:

```
    <LinearLayout 
      androids:id="@+id/time_slot_container"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is super-simple TimeSlotFragment.java:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public class TimeSlotFragment extends Fragment {

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_slot, container, false);
  }
}
```

... and time_slot.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:hint="action"
    >
    <requestFocus />
  </EditText>

  <EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:hint="time"
    android:inputType="number"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you should use ViewPager & inside it pass the different instances of the same fragment.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors or any other output... unless I put in my own System.out, which work, so I know it's hitting the code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try putting a Layout (May be FrameLayout) within the LinearLayout as you are replacing complete contentView is causing the problem.